# django enumerate a model's integer field when another model gets created

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models

class Game(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=8192)

class GamePreview(models.Model):
    game = models.OneToOneField(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comments = models.IntegerField(default=0) # Want to + 1 this when a comment gets created

class GameComment(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    @classmethod # does not work
    def create(cls, game):
        comment = cls(game=game)
        preview = GamePreview.objects.get(game=comment.game)
        preview.comments += 1
        return preview
```

Basically, I have a GamePreview model that has a IntgerField that should show the amount of comments, but I cannot figure out how I can do preview.comments += 1 when a GameComment gets created...

Comment: Please *don't*, you can annotate the `GamePreview` object to determin the number of comments.

Answer (score 2):

Please *don't*, you can annotate the `GamePreview` object to determin the number of comments.

You thus can remove the `comments` field:

```
class GamePreview(models.Model):
    game = models.OneToOneField(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # no comments
```

and then in case you need the number of related `GameComment`s, you can work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Count

GamePreview.objects.annotate(
    comments=Count('game__gamecomment')
)
```

`GamePreview` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.comments` that contains the number of *related* `GameComment`s.

---

If you really want to increment the number of comments, you can work with:

```
class GameComment(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    @classmethod # does not work
    def create(cls, game, comment):
        comment = cls(game=game, comment=comment)
        preview = GamePreview.objects.get(game_id=comment.game_id)
        preview.comments = F('comments') + 1
        preview.save()
        return comment
```

But this is usually *not* a good idea: if a comment is removed, or no longer belongs to that game but to another, you will need to write some logic to change this. Often it is quite hard to cover *all* possible cases.

Comment: ok... sorry if this sound stupid but where do I actually put/use '''GamePreview.objects.annotate(
    comments=Count('game__gamecomment')
)''', in the serializer or maybe send it as a request to the frontend?

Comment: @Luna: in the `ViewSet` you can define an annotated queryset, and then serialize these fields in the serializer.